# Is <non-object> kind of memory link or abandoned memory?

Tags: iphone, ios, memory, instruments

I'm using instruments to tracking memory usage. Heapshot Analysis is awesome, but I also found some "non-object". what's this? kind of abandoned memory or something else ? How to solve this ?

[image: Heap shot image]

Another Question may relate,
I used to use
[myObj release], myObj = nil;
myObj = [[MyObj alloc] init];

to release object and create a new one. (myObj = nil, just for avoid crash)
 Some guy said, It may waste memory performance. Is he right? 
 I want to know some details.
 Very appreciate for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question has an answer here:
[What does <non-object> in Allocation "heapshots" mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4079253/what-does-non-object-in-allocation-heapshots-mean)

For the memory management there's absolutely nothing wrong in your code. myObj = nil is pointless because you're allocating a new object in the line after it.

Comment: could just use a property :) btw hi valerio :)